# How exactly does the "threshold" property of a raycaster work in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, graphics, 3d, raytracing

I am using raytracing to select invisible bounding boxes around buildings.
When using THREE.Raycaster with default settings, way too many buildings were being selected (see
[Img 1: Result with default precision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uOcR.png))

So I looked into the Raycaster docs and found .params, which has the following properties:

```
{ 
    Mesh: {},
    Line: { threshold: 1 },
    LOD: {},
    Points: { threshold: 1 },
    Sprite: {} 
}
```

When I set .params.Line.threshold to 0.01, it works almost as intended. But for some reason, it seems almost "too precise", as in, when I click on points that definitely intersect with a bbox, they don't register as such.

Images [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QemTV.png) and [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlKRc.png) show clicks that did not intersect, and Images [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c489r.png) and [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdBXJ.png) show clicks that "worked". As you can see, clicks 2 and 3 were definitely within the bounding boxes.

I had assumed the threshold simply dictates the radius of the ray. But in that case, no matter the threshold, clicks *within* the geometry should always intersect with the boxes, right?
Does the ray maybe consider other things, such as proximity to the edge of the geometry, orientation of the face hit, etc.?
Or is something else at play here?

Comment: You can see all of the math behind a `Ray` intersecting with a bounding `Box3D` in the source code for [`Ray.intersectBox`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/70cc4e192fe2ebd0bf8542a81c8c513d61984c58/src/math/Ray.js#L323) . The `threshold` property actually only applies to `Line` and `Points` objects ([`Line.raycast`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/70cc4e192fe2ebd0bf8542a81c8c513d61984c58/src/objects/Line.js#L77), [`Points.raycast`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/70cc4e192fe2ebd0bf8542a81c8c513d61984c58/src/objects/Points.js#L42)). r152

Comment: I realize now I should have included more accurate information. I was actually intersecting with Box3Helpers of said boxes (to visualize once clicked), which appear to be made up of LineSegments. That explains it. Thank you for pointing me towards the source code!